# jQuery on click event not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a function that I want to call when an item in a drop down (id=ddlTest) list besides the first one is clicked. Below is the code I have. It works fine in IE but not Chrome, any idea why?

```
jQuery('#ddlTest').on('click', 'option:gt(0)', function() {
    alert('test'); //never runs
});
```

**Update**: I got the below working but it can easily be broken if the user clicks the DDL and then off of it

```
var ddlCounter = 1;
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#ddlTest").on('click', function () {
        if (ddlCounter % 2 === 0) {
            if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {
                showHideFunction();
            }
        }
        ddlCounter += 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: When something works in IE and not in Chrome you know you've got a serious problem. What errors do you get in Chrome's console?

Comment: I know! I get no errors. No problem selecting the options either

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah tis true - I've been working with dynamic DOM elements all day - mind is still there xD Will remove my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably add a click event on a specific `option` element within a `select`.

A better alternative would be to put a `change` event handler on a `select` and then check the `index()` of the chosen option:

```js
$('#ddlTest').on('change', 'select', function() {
  var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
  if (index == 0) {
    console.log('You chose the first option');
  } else {
    console.log('You did not choose the first option');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ddlTest">
  <select>
  <option>Please select</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I originally had a change event but I had to change it because the same code needs to run even when the same option in the DDL is re-selected

Comment: In which case you can use the same logic as above, but with `'click'` instead of `'change'`, but be aware that this goes against all accessibility guidelines

Comment: The drop down list on my page shows and hides other divs depending on what is selected. This works the first time but when I go back to re-select a different option it fires the same code when the arrow in the box is clicked since the index is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript's [selectedIndex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) property will be better and faster

```
$("#ddlTest").on('change', function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {
        alert("Greater than zero");
    } else {
        alert("Zero");
    }
});
```

check it out here: https://plnkr.co/edit/2dZp5ZGA8A4l65wt5u3k?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I would like to avoid change because the same code needs to run when the same DDL item is re-selected

Comment: @cooper, you can use mouseup instead of change then.

Comment: plunk with mouseup: https://plnkr.co/edit/6ZeBI72AgwJTQEE0qu3h?p=preview

Comment: But then the code runs even when the drop down arrow is clicked. Is there any way to avoid this? I only want the function I have to be called when an option besides the first one in the DDL is clicked

Comment: You can just return if the selectedIndex = 0. I have updated the plunk. https://plnkr.co/edit/6ZeBI72AgwJTQEE0qu3h?p=preview